# Why didn't the goverment put Mr. Newberry into witness protection if his testimony was so much life threatening?

Tags: plot-explanation, grosse-pointe-blank

Spoilers ahead, so read at your own discretion!

Towards end of the movie [*Grosse Pointe Blank* (1997)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119229/) we learn that Debi's father Bart is being hunted by assassins. After being escorted to his house by Martin he tells Debi: "They're trying to kill me. My testimony." We don't hear much about the details but it's clear that his testimony was life threatening (at least for us, the viewers). Why wasn't he put into the witness protection program? Was it so, just to make the plot easier to bring everyone into the same location without any additional gunfight to tune down the violence?

Comment: Minor detail: Dad's name isn't Mr. Bart. It's Bart Newberry.

Comment: I've written it like that because IMDB lists his name as "Mr. Bart Newberry".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not anything in the movie to outright say why, but my guess is - within the reality of the movie - they never thought it would be that big a deal. I can't find a clip, but in the scene where Martin rescues Debi's dad, as they get out of the car at his house, dad says "Design division wants me dead over a leaky sunroof? You want to kill me because of THAT?" He's genuinely surprised it's come to this.

Edit: Found a clip on Youtube.

2:02:15 in case it doesn't come right up.

Comment: I've just watched that part about the "leaky sunroof". You are right about him being surprised. I can't vote yet on your answer but will when the day is over :)